# Does the following error log xss attack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xss

I've just found the following error that logged at `window.onerror` from one of my user:

```
{"message":"\"nativka already initialized\"","file":"https://staticcf0.ntvk1.ru/nvv.js","line":"12","fileName":"https://staticcf0.ntvk1.ru/nvv.js","lineNumber":"12"}
```

I don't include `nvv.js` none of my page. Is it trying to add xss to my site?

Comment: could be from a userscript, bookmarklet, or extension.

Comment: Or someone could locally add this script to your website.

Comment: @duskwuff:- its a system bug user's system https://www.exedb.com/en/nvv.js/1014434 not related to website.

Comment: @RaviSharma That website doesn't prove anything one way or another. It shows that the file was found as part of a downloaded web page (e.g, "save page as").

Comment: @Ravi Sharma so may I to ignore this because it doesn't relate to my security issues?

Comment: @Erik :- ya sure you can ignore it..its a client side security fault you are not responsible for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a security fault from user side. User may installed something malicious softwares on their PC thats why this error occurring. You are safe but i suggest for cross checking you need to check console log on your Machine or on another machines. 
                                                                Another way is to comment all Js part and test your site.

Comment: I've just checked my site on my and another machine and don't see this error. It's seems on my problem. Thanks for the answer